# Inflating Drawables from XML in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to extend a drawable (just like how shapes work, create your own tag) and allow it to be inflated from XML?  Or is drawable only for the allowed 9 types?

Comment: Do you want to write back Drawable object to XML document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use your own drawable classes from XML.

Comment: They are often loaded into other processes where custom classes can not be loaded.  It is very useful to be have a guarantee that any particular drawable can be loaded and displayed by any app.